# Making sense of translational invariance of the heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, symmetric-groups, heat-equation

The 1-D heat equation $u_t=\gamma u_{xx}$ admits the transformation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \mbox{ translation along x}$$

The solution $u$ is invariant. This means it exhibits translational invariance. Then, if we transform it along $x$, we get

$$u(x,t) \rightarrow u(x-a,t)$$

Both are solutions, because symmetries "transform solutions to solutions". What does this mean, though. Does it mean

$$u(x,t)=u(x-a,t)?$$

because an invariant doesn't change under transformation? The definition of invariant is $u(x') \equiv  u(x)$, or equivalently, if we use the infinitesimal generator of the transformation $\hat{U}$: $\hat{U}u=0$. Then it must be true that

$$u(x,t)=u(x-a,t)$$

But this would mean, that I can select $a$ arbitrarily and then $u$ is exactly the same anywhere along $x$. Then $u=\mbox{const}$, correct? This cannot be true.
Where is the mistake? What is the meaning and what is the usefulness of this invariance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean $u(x,t) = u(x-a,t)$, since then the solutions would be constants. Rather, it means that if you define another function $\psi(x,t) = u(x-a,t)$, then $\psi$ is also a solution. You note this above. THat's what it means.

Comment: I agree that it cannot mean this; please see above I edited the question to emphasize the point of confusion

Comment: Could you point out the mistake; and explain the benefit of the invariance.